# partial summation $\displaystyle{\sum_{p\leq X}f(p)/p}$ via $\displaystyle{\sum_{p\leq X}f(p)\log p}$.

Tags: integration, elementary-number-theory, summation, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

In some paper I saw that to show that some inequality of this type
$$
\sum_{p\leq X}\frac{f(p)}p>\frac{\log^2X}{C_1}
$$
it says the above inequality followes using by partial summation if we show
$$
\sum_{p\leq X}f(p)\log p>\frac{2X\log^2X}{C_2}.
$$
My question is "is it a general method in analytic number theory or it depends on the problem and the estimates that we can do easier in the second inequality in that problem"?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a consequence of the [Abel's summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_summation_formula). We have that $$\sum_{p\leq x}\frac{f\left(p\right)}{p}=\sum_{p\leq x}f\left(p\right)\log\left(p\right)\frac{1}{p\log\left(p\right)}
 $$ $$=\frac{1}{x\log\left(x\right)}\sum_{p\leq x}f\left(p\right)\log\left(p\right)+\int_{2}^{x}\frac{\sum_{p\leq t}f\left(p\right)\log\left(p\right)\left(\log\left(t\right)+1\right)}{t^{2}\log^{2}\left(t\right)}dt
 $$ so if $$\sum_{p\leq x}f\left(p\right)\log\left(p\right)>\frac{2x\log^{2}\left(x\right)}{C_{2}}
 $$ we have $$\sum_{p\leq x}\frac{f\left(p\right)}{p}\geq\frac{2\log\left(x\right)}{C_{2}}+\frac{2}{C_{2}}\int_{2}^{x}\frac{\log\left(t\right)+1}{t}dt
 $$ $$=\frac{4\log\left(x\right)}{C_{2}}+\frac{\log^{2}\left(x\right)}{C_{2}}+C_{3}>\color{red}{\frac{\log^{2}\left(x\right)}{C_{2}}}$$

Comment: thanks, I also did the same calculations, but I wanted to know if transfering from $f(p)/p$ to $f(p)\log p$ is a general method, why it does not find directly the $\sum_{p\leq X}f(p)/p$, perhaps the reason was that the calculation of the second one in this problem was easier.

Comment: @asad It is not a general method. Using the Abel's summation you have essentially two tools: you can "separate" the sum of some functions and you have to evaluate an integral instead of a sum. So in this case, considering the bound and the function in the sum, everything works correctly. But using other functions or another bound the process could be not so nice.